# How to close all open JQuery dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Before upgrading to the newest library for jQuery I was using this code to close any open dialogs. Now this code just throws an error.

```
  $(".dialogs:ui-dialog").each(function () {

            if ($(this).data('dialog').isOpen()) {
               $(this).dialog('close');
          };
 });
```

What I need to accomplish is when a jQuery dialog is open and the user clicks on a menu item to open another dialog I need to make sure that all other dialogs are closed before the new one is opened.

What is the new code to use to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why can't you directly use `$( ".dialogs" ).dialog( "close" );`? If the dialog is not open, I imagine close won't do anything.

Comment: I can't imagine that code used to work (I don't think that's how the API exposed `isOpen`). The way it seems you should use it is like: `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "isOpen" )`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I agree - but I wonder if the `close` event is still triggered for every element (open or not), which *might* affect other things

Comment: @Ian: if affected something, that would be a bug on the library ;) It should not cause any problem closing an already closed dialog.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi No, what I mean is like say the OP has some code that runs when a dialog's `close` event is triggered...say saving all form fields to their DB. If the `close` event is triggered for already closed dialogs (which is what we're not sure about), it can cause unnecessary AJAX calls. I didn't mean anything in the jQuery UI library :)

Comment: @Ian: just checked the code, it just returns in case `_isOpen == false`

Comment: It will error, believe me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use

```
$( ".dialogs" ).dialog( "close" );
```

If you check the [dialog source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js) you'll see that closing an already closed dialog have no effect so you can safely use it

```
close: function( event ) {
    var that = this;

    if ( !this._isOpen || this._trigger( "beforeClose", event ) === false ) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to keep your logic similar to what you have for any reason, you could use this

```
$(".dialogs").each(function () {
    var $dialog = $(this);
    if ($dialog.dialog('isOpen')) {
        $dialog.dialog('close');
    };
});
```

Comment: Ahh good find on whether already closed dialogs have their `close` event triggered :)

Comment: I get an error '$(...).dialog is not a function' This closes the dialog but leaves behind the dark background.